# Some polite/alternative way of saying "due to the lack of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

I have been writing my SOP for grad school and I'm looking for polite ways of saying "due to the lack of".

Currently, I have this sentence:

> I analyse and solve system defects that occur **in lieu of**
>   well-thought-out specifications, poor design decisions, bad coding
>   practices or simply due to miscommunication

I am not sure if this is correct use of "in lieu of" and can be seen as somewhat critical of other's work.
Any help?

Comment: Your text doesn't really make sense. Note that *in lieu of* means ***instead of*** (as a replacement for), not *due to the lack of*. But just because what you specialise in is "fixing" problems, does that really justify you criticising the practices that might have led to those problems in the first place? I'd leave that bit out completely, as it gives the impression you might be a poor team-player always looking to blame someone else when things go wrong.

Comment: Your last statement is exactly what I fear. I am not at all like that. I work on the operations side of a large software project and fix failures in the production environment (imagine people fixing outages of google.com).

Comment: I always liked to style myself as a ***troubleshooter*** (fixing clagged up computer systems), but the golden rule was "Never criticise whoever installed or chose the system that now doesn't work". Same as the salesman's dictum "Don't knock the competition". It only gets someone's back up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers this is especially true when it's an older system and when digging through the history, you discover that it was _you_ that messed it up in the first place. #oops

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Been there, done that, got the t-shirt!  But at least sometimes you can avoid having to explicitly *tell* people it was your own fault. Not so good when you've publicly gobbed off about what "some moron" did that you now need to fix, and it then turns out you have to work closely with the guy to establish exactly what his code was *trying* to achieve, before you can figure out what to replace it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>***Note***: This does not directly answer the question, but instead attempts to answer intent.</sup>

> I analyse and solve system defects that occur in lieu of well-thought-out specifications, poor design decisions, bad coding practices or simply due to miscommunication

You switch from "positive" to "negative" causes here.

Because you are looking for something more *polite*, I'm going to recommend changing the sentence to convey something about *you*. It is not polite to place blame.
<sub>*Please make sure that you actually do these things before you claim that you do by copy-pasting.*</sub>

> I analyse and solve system defects ***by providing*** well-thought-out specifications, good design decisions, good coding practices and clear communication.

Comment: Well, I had thought of this but saying that I provide software specifications would be wrong. The rest I totally do. Maybe I am better off completely dropping the *"well-thought-out specifications"* part and using the positive tone. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is some contradiction in your subsequent terms as well-thought-out is positive rather than the rest which are negative so I have changed that

A common more formal suggestion

I analyse and solve system defects that occur **as a result of** weak specifications, poor design decisions, bad coding practices or simply due to miscommunication

Answer (score 2):

The [Plain English Campaign](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/) recommends replacing constructions such as  
 <strike>*due to the lack of*</strike>, *as a result of*, *owing to* and so on with the simpler and less wordy *because of*.

Comment: Huh? *Due to the lack of* doesn't mean the same thing as *because of* at all. *Due to the lack of bread, we will be serving cake today.* isn't the same as *because of the bread, we will be serving cake today.*

Comment: I agree. However, I believe "owing to" fits my sentence. Might need to negate the positive as highlighted by @KJO in their answer.

Comment: Apologies, an embarrassingly unhelpful and incorrect inclusion in my answer, which I have now struck through.